# How can I check my byte flag, verifying that a specific bit is at 1 or 0?

Tags: c, math, binary, bit-manipulation

I use a byte to store some flag like `10101010`, and I would like to know how to verify that a specific bit is at `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here's a function that can be used to test any `bit`:

```
bool is_bit_set(unsigned value, unsigned bitindex)
{
    return (value & (1 << bitindex)) != 0;
}
```

**Explanation**:

The [left shift operator](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/binary#bitwise-operators) `<<` creates a [bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitmask). To illustrate:

- `(1 << 0)` equals `00000001`
- `(1 << 1)` equals `00000010`
- `(1 << 3)` equals `00001000`

So a shift of `0` tests the rightmost bit.  A shift of `31` would be the leftmost bit of a 32-bit value.

The [bitwise-and operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-and-operator-amp?view=msvc-170) (`&`) gives a result where all the bits that are `1` on both sides are set.  Examples:

- `1111 & 0001` equals `0001`
- `1111 & 0010` equals `0010`
- `0000 & 0001` equals `0000`.

So, the expression:

```
(value & (1 << bitindex))
```

will return the bitmask if the associated bit (`bitindex`) contains a `1`
in that position, or else it will return `0` (meaning it does **not** contain a `1` at the assoicated `bitindex`).

To simplify, the expression tests if the result is greater than `zero`.

- If `Result > 0` returns `true`, meaning the byte has a `1` in the tested
  `bitindex` position.
- All else returns `false` meaning the result was zero, which means there's a `0` in tested `bitindex` position.

Note the `!= 0` is not required in the statement since it's a [bool](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bool-in-c/), but I like to make it explicit.

Comment: How about an assert when bitindex is > 31 ?

Comment: I think the current functionality, which would return false in that case, is proper...

Comment: Why bit shift I do not understand :(

Comment: It's really just an example, intended to demonstrate how to test bits.  In production code you might want to add some error checking, but that would only add noise here.

Comment: Shifting will remote what in my example? All bit to the left?

Comment: You bit shift to move the 1 to the correct position.  If bit index is 3, then you are shifting 1 left 3, so you are checking against 0x000...0100

Comment: ok the bitindex is read from 0 to 7 from the right to the left ! I got it I think!

Comment: Correct. Although the example where Kristopher shifts (1 << 3) should be 00001000 I believe

Comment: Regarding luke's question: This is endian safe.  The left and right shift operators always consider the least-significant bit to be on the "right" and the most significant on the "left", regardless of byte order.

Comment: Also is* is a reserved namespace, although some would argue it's pedantic.

Answer (score 6):

As an extension of [Patrick Desjardins' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127027/how-can-i-check-my-byte-flag-verifying-that-a-specific-bit-is-at-1-or-0/127033#127033):

When doing bit-manipulation it **really** helps to have a very solid knowledge of [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Also the bitwise "AND" operator in C is `&`, so you want to do this:

```
unsigned char a = 0xAA; // 10101010 in hex
unsigned char b = (1 << bitpos); // Where bitpos is the position you want to check

if(a & b) {
    //bit set
}

else {
    //not set
}
```

Above I used the bitwise "AND" (& in C) to check whether a particular bit was set or not. I also used two different ways of formulating binary numbers. I highly recommend you check out the Wikipedia link above.

Comment: There is no reason for you to have to store the bitshift in a certain variable, I was using it as an example of a bitwise operator. However if you dont bitshift you will have to use an explicit value somewhere. The bitshift I used was an easy way to do 00000100 where bitpos is 2 in this example

Answer (score 4):

You can use an AND operator. The example you have: 10101010 and you want to check the third bit you can do: (10101010 AND 00100000) and if you get 00100000 you know that you have the flag at the third position to 1.

Comment: C doesn't have an "AND" operator. Furthermore, you need to use a bitwise AND, not a logical one.

Answer (score 4):

[Kristopher Johnson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127027/how-can-i-check-my-byte-flag-verifying-that-a-specific-bit-is-at-1-or-0/127062#127062) is very good if you like working with individual fields like this.  I prefer to make the code easier to read by using bit fields in C.

For example:

```
struct fieldsample
{
  unsigned short field1 : 1;
  unsigned short field2 : 1;
  unsigned short field3 : 1;
  unsigned short field4 : 1;
}
```

Here you have a simple struct with four fields, each 1 bit in size.  Then you can write your code using simple structure access.

```
void codesample()
{
  //Declare the struct on the stack.
  fieldsample fields;
  //Initialize values.
  fields.f1 = 1;
  fields.f2 = 0;
  fields.f3 = 0;
  fields.f4 = 1;
  ...
  //Check the value of a field.
  if(fields.f1 == 1) {}
  ...
}
```

You get the same small size advantage, plus readable code because you can give your fields meaningful names inside the structure.

Comment: Note that a problem with using bit fields is that the way they are laid out in memory is implementation-dependent, so it might be difficult to use them with data that you exchange with other programs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++ and the standard library is allowed, I'd suggest storing your flags in a bitset:

```
#include <bitset>
//...
std::bitset<8> flags(someVariable);
```

as then you can check and set flags using the [] indexing operator.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody's been wrong so far, but to give a method to check an arbitrary bit:

```
int checkBit( byte in, int bit )
{
  return in & ( 1 << bit );
}
```

If the function returns non-zero, the bit is set.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte THIRDBIT = 4; // 4 = 00000100 i.e third bit is set

int isThirdBitSet(byte in) {
 return in & THIRDBIT; // Returns 1 if the third bit is set, 0 otherwise
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as [Patrick Desjardins says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127027/how-can-i-check-my-byte-flag-verifying-that-a-specific-bit-is-at-1-or-0/127033#127033) and you make a bit-to-bit OR to the resulting of the previous AND operation.

In this case, you will have a final result of 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, to check if the lowest bit is set, this will look something like:

```
int MY_FLAG = 0x0001;
if ((value & MY_FLAG) == MY_FLAG)
    doSomething();
```

Comment: That tests that a specific bit *and only that bit* is set.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bitwise (not logical!) AND to compare the value against a bitmask.

```
if (var & 0x08) {
  /* The fourth bit is set */
}
```