# Javascript Math.ceil(Math.abs()) optimization

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, bit-manipulation

I'm using `Math.ceil( Math.abs( x ) )`  inside a loop.

Can anyone realize any optimization for this operation? (Bitwise or what?)

You are welcome to benchmark at [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com)

Comment: ps: I need the return value of the operation, not the condition it's < or > something

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't get any simpler than you've made it.

Comment: I've changed the test value to a negative float instead of an integer, so that the code actually has to do something.

Comment: From what I can see in WebKit sources, JavaScript methods `Math.abs()` and `Math.ceil()` use C++ cmath functions [`fabs()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fabs/) and [`ceil()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/ceil/). I really don't think you could optimize that. Are you sure that this is a problem? Could you post code that you're using?

Comment: @Crozin: there's overhead is looking up and calling the functions (dynamic dispatch), of which you can get rid of by only using operators (static dispatch)

Comment: hi everybody! posted final benchmarking but smth not working yet http://jsperf.com/best-math-ceil-math-abs

Comment: @Dan - The ones you have posted there do not solve the problem you asked, nor is it clear what you mean by "pixel size". Anyway, I have removed mine: as pointed out it was wrong too.

Comment: @Crozin: these calculations are used in animation tight loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Math.abs doesn't get simpler according to webkit JavaScriptCore

```
case MathObjectImp::Abs:
result = ( arg < 0 || arg == -0) ? (-arg) : arg;
```

However ceil uses C's ceil function

```
 case MathObjectImp::Ceil:
    result = ::ceil(arg);
```

so testing on JSpref
http://jsperf.com/math-ceil-vs-bitwise
**bitwise is faster** 
testing @orangedog's answer http://jsperf.com/math-ceil-vs-bitwise/2 Math.ceil is faster

So I guess your best choice is:

```
var n = Math.abs(x);
var f = (n << 0),
f = f == n ? f : f + 1;
```

Comment: Thumbs up, you've done a great investigation in the Webkit source!

Answer (score 3):

`x < 0 ? Math.ceil(-x) : Math.ceil(x)` produces a 40% speedup in Firefox 3.6 (little difference in the others) while remaining relatively readable.

Here is the [jsPerf page](http://jsperf.com/math-ceil-math-abs-x/6). Ignore the "some bitwise operators" label; the expression above doesn't use any.

Comment: I [found with jsperf](http://jsperf.com/two-max-bound-functions) that doing some bitwise stuff is faster than a ceiling function in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript isn't a compiled language like C, so bitwise operations that can work wonders in such languages, aren't so great in JS because numbers are stored as 64 bit floating points. Take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003879/understanding-bitwise-operations-in-javascript).

Even then, what you write in JS will get transformed to native code somehow by underlying browser and it might be faster or slower, depending on implementation.

Since `Math.ceil` and `Math.abs` are built in; I'd guess they're heavily optimized, so I doubt you'll be able to get better performance by doing some trickery of your own.

Bottom line: three things stand in your way of doing it faster:

1. number representation in JS
2. fact that it's an interpreted language
3. functions you use are "native", so they should be fast enough on their own

Comment: you're forgetting about dispatch overhead - using operators instead of methods will most likely speed up the code

Comment: Although seemingly in JS numbers are all doubles, all JS engines actually store values at integers when possible, so bitwise operators are still quick as there's no conversion needed when the number is already an integer.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt(Math.abs(x)) + 1` is faster by about 30% on Firefox according to jsperf

As the argument is always positive, the branches in Math.ceil() are unnecessary.

Comment: It may or may not be faster but it's also wrong - any number with a zero value fractional component will be incorrectly 1 greater than the ceil'd value.

Comment: Ah, good point. Checking for this, unsurprisingly, makes it slower again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one, which doesn't need to do any lookup:

```
((x >= 0 ? x : -x) + 0.5) >> 0
```

Comment: The rounding here is `Math.round` not `Math.ceil`.

Answer (score -2):

Two fastest ways to do calculations (giving almost the same speed in modern browsers):

```
function f (n) {
   return (~~n) + 1;
}

// or 

function f1 (n) {
   return (n | 0) + 1;
}

// some tests, ~~ operator seems to work identicaly on numbers:

( 3.3 | 0 ) === 3;   
( 3.8 | 0 ) === 3;   
( -3.3 | 0 ) === -3; 
( -3.8 | 0 ) === -3;
```

unlike `Math.floor(-3.3) == Math.floor(-3.8) == -4`

Comment: `f1(1); // 2.` These functions don't follow `Math.ceil` behaviour. Perhaps you should accept the top-rated answer, rather than your own.