# Is the Math.abs takes more time to execute in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I am using Math.abs for my 1000 points as below

```
Math.abs(a - b) < tolerance;
```

My profiler shows that Math.abs uses 62 ms, I need to optimize it, so tried this

```
((a-b) < 0 ?-(a-b) : a-b) < tolerance;
```

I want to know which is better and fast

Comment: Is it **the real bottleneck** in your application?

Comment: Try testing it!  You've already written the code, so why are you asking here?

Comment: @aga It seems that this code runs a 1000 times. So yes, that can be a performance issue.

Comment: Test both at http://jsperf.com/

Comment: What does your profiler say about the optimization?

Comment: Proof that profilers are useless :D It is physically impossible for Math.abs to take 62ms for 1000 calls. You probably interpreted it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on the browser (and version) used as you can see in this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/math-abs-vs-bitwise/6) and is discussed in [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614768/javascript-math-ceilmath-abs-optimization):

Anno 2013 one could state that:

- `Math.abs()` is mostly fastest in IE, FireFox and Safari
- Bitwise `(x ^ (x >> 31)) - (x >> 31)` is mostly fastest in Chrome and Operah
- Ternary `(x < 0 ? -x : x)`  was only the fastest in FireFox 3.x and 4 era.

You could provide a dynamic function-loader to initiate the optimal function (based on live in-browser speed-profiling or browser-detection), containing the fastest routine for that browser.
Naturally this comes at a couple of costs:

- time wasted on browser-profiling (reliability while loading the page) or browser-detection (well, reliability in general..)
- extra bandwidth for larger javascript
- (usually) larger memory-footprint (because on the fly generated functions are often slower then static defined functions (that are given the proper indentifier)

So in general I'd prefer:
`Mah.abs()` (since that is often the smallest and clearly indicates intent).
Followed by the ternary (often coupled with the comma-operator by which I can perform more logic with just one test, this can be both faster/shorter and even require less programming-logic).
Finally the bitwise variant reveals the least intent, doesn't offer some of the above ternary-advantages AND only works reliable if you have no more than 32 bits..

Hope this helps!