# Enum flags in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, enums, flags

I need to emulate enum type in Javascript and approach seems pretty straight forward:

```
var MyEnum = {Left = 1; Right = 2; Top = 4; Bottom = 8}
```

Now, in C# I could combine those values like this:

```
MyEnum left_right = MyEnum.Left | MyEnum.Right
```

and then I can test if enum has certain value:

```
if (left_right & MyEnum.Left == MyEnum.Left) {...}
```

Can I do something like that in Javascript?

Comment: Note that the object syntax is wrong for MyEnum.  CMS already provided a corrected example in his answer.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In javascript you should be able to combine them as:

```
var left_right = MyEnum.Left | MyEnum.Right;
```

Then testing would be exactly as it is in your example of

```
if ( (left_right & MyEnum.Left) == MyEnum.Left) {...}
```

Answer (score 101):

You just have to use the [bitwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) operators:

```
var myEnum = {
  left: 1,
  right: 2,
  top: 4,
  bottom: 8
}

var myConfig = myEnum.left | myEnum.right;

if (myConfig & myEnum.right) {
  // right flag is set
}
```

More info:

- [Understanding bitwise operations in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003879/)
- [How to check my byte flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127027)

Answer (score 17):

Yes, bitwise arithmetic works in Javascript.  You have to be careful with it because Javascript only has the `Number` data type, which is implemented as a floating-point type.  But, values are converted to *signed* 32-bit values for bitwise operations.  So as long as you don't try to use more than 31 bits, you'll be fine.

Comment: Interesting point. So you are talking just over a hundred items in the set which is definitely out there for usecases.

Answer (score 7):

There is my implementation in typescript:

```
export class FlagEnumService {

    constructor(private value: number = 0) {
    }

    public get() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public set(value: number): this {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }

    public has(key: number): boolean {
        return !!(this.value & key);
    }

    public add(key: number): this {
        this.value |= key;
        return this;
    }

    public delete(key: number): this {
        this.value &= ~key;
        return this;
    }

    public toggle(key: number): this {
        this.has(key) ? this.delete(key) : this.add(key);
        return this;
    }
}
```

And tests for clarification

```
import { FlagEnumService } from './flag-enum.service';

enum Test {
    None = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 4,
    Four = 8
}

describe('FlagEnumService', () => {
    let service: FlagEnumService;
    beforeEach(() => service = new FlagEnumService());

    it('should create with initial value', () => {
        service = new FlagEnumService(Test.First);
        expect(service.get()).toBe(Test.First);
    });

    it('should return true if has flag', () => {
        service = new FlagEnumService(Test.First);
        expect(service.has(Test.First)).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should return false if doesn\'t have flag', () => {
        service = new FlagEnumService(Test.First);
        expect(service.has(Test.Second)).toBe(false);
    });

    it('should add', () => {
        expect(service.add(Test.First).add(Test.Second).get()).toBe(Test.First + Test.Second);
    });

    it('should not add the same value twice', () => {
        expect(service.add(Test.First).add(Test.First).get()).toBe(Test.First);
    });

    it('should remove', () => {
        expect(
            service
                .add(Test.First)
                .add(Test.Second)
                .delete(Test.Second)
                .get()
        )
            .toBe(Test.First);
    });

    it('should return 0 when add then remove the same value', () => {
        expect(service.add(Test.First).delete(Test.First).get()).toBe(0);
    });

    it('should not remove not added values', () => {
        expect(service.add(Test.First).delete(Test.Second).get()).toBe(Test.First);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I've tried to create an example that demonstrates a common use case where one may want to use bit mask enums to control logging verbosity. It demonstrates the us of JavaScript bit-wise operations: **[See it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mishrsud/VPY2p/1/)**

```
/*
 * Demonstration of how a Flags enum can be simulated in JavaScript and 
 * Used to control what gets logged based on user passed value
 */

// A Flags Enum (sort-of)
var LogLevels = {
    NONE: 0,
    INFO: 1,
    TRACE: 2,
    DEBUG: 4,
    WARN: 8,
    ERROR: 16,
    FATAL: 32
};

// Initialize
var currLogLevel = LogLevels.NONE;

// User Sets a log level
var logLevel = LogLevels.WARN;

// Convert the configured logLvel to a bit-masked enum value
switch (logLevel) {
    case LogLevels.INFO:
        currLogLevel = LogLevels.INFO | LogLevels.TRACE | LogLevels.DEBUG | LogLevels.WARN | LogLevels.ERROR | LogLevels.FATAL;
        break;
    case LogLevels.TRACE:
        currLogLevel = LogLevels.TRACE | LogLevels.DEBUG | LogLevels.WARN | LogLevels.ERROR | LogLevels.FATAL;
        break;
    case LogLevels.DEBUG:
        currLogLevel = LogLevels.DEBUG | LogLevels.WARN | LogLevels.ERROR | LogLevels.FATAL;
        break;
    case LogLevels.WARN:
        currLogLevel = LogLevels.WARN | LogLevels.ERROR | LogLevels.FATAL;
        break;
    case LogLevels.ERROR:
    case LogLevels.FATAL:
    default:
        currLogLevel = LogLevels.ERROR | LogLevels.FATAL;
}

// Example: log verbosity set to WARN, so this would NOT be logged
if ((currLogLevel & LogLevels.DEBUG) == LogLevels.DEBUG) {
    console.log("log DEBUG");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Flag Enumerations in JavaScript**

Flag enums: Values must increment by powers of 2

```
var SEASONS = {
  Spring : 1,
  Summer : 2,
  Fall   : 4,
  Winter : 8
};
```

Cannot use 0 in a bitwise `&` operation to test for a flag b/c it will
always result in zero. However, it can be used for logical comparisons.

**Usage examples (contrived)**

```
var getSeasonsSelected = function( seasons ) {
  var selected = [];

  // The perens are needed around the bitwise operation due to the
  // greater operator precedence of `===`
  if ( (seasons & SEASONS.Spring) === SEASONS.Spring ) selected.push('Spring');
  if ( (seasons & SEASONS.Summer) === SEASONS.Summer ) selected.push('Summer');
  if ( (seasons & SEASONS.Fall)   === SEASONS.Fall )   selected.push('Fall');
  if ( (seasons & SEASONS.Winter) === SEASONS.Winter ) selected.push('Winter');

  return selected;
};

var s1 = getSeasonsSelected( SEASONS.Spring | SEASONS.Fall );
console.log(s1);
//=> ["Spring", "Fall"]
```