# What is a flag variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, flags

Recently I came across flag variables, but I have no idea what they do.

I am little unsure about when to use a flag variable and how to go about it.

I Googled it but there weren't any specific examples related to my context (of JavaScript).

Comment: Asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626263/enum-flags-in-javascript

Comment: my first hit in google http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/valid2.shtml

Comment: look at that example,its pretty confusing!!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Flag Variables Defined and Uses](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/valid2.shtml) says:

> A flag variable, in its simplest form, is a variable you define to have one value until some condition is true, in which case you change the variable's value.  It is a variable you can use to control the flow of a function or statement, allowing you to check for certain conditions while your function progresses.

As an example:

```js
// errors is the flag variable
var errors = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if(i == 6) {  // Your error condition
    errors++;
  }
}

if(errors) {  // Is the flag "up"? (i.e. > 0)
  alert("There was a problem!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A flag is a variable used to have some value until some condition becomes true,then we change it to false and print the output  (Initially flag considered as true)

Comment: In that case it would start out as false and switch to true, not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

Flag variables are the same for all languages, whether it's RUBY, Python, Javascript or C++.

A flag variable is usually given one value, `0` or `1`, `True` or `False`. It's used as a Boolean variable where the result toggles between 0 (False) and 1 (True) or as used by the programmer. Some prefer `flag = 0` and change it to `flag = 1` in the program to perform an action.

Answer (score 1):

A flag variable, it is a variable you define to have one value until some condition is true or false in which case you change the variable's value. It is a variable you can use to control the flow of a function or statement, allowing you to check for certain conditions while your function executing.

Flag variable is same in every language

Flag variable is boolean variable.