# Show/hide multiple rows in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows

I have this table that have rows with different classes and then checkboxes for buttons.
When I click one of the buttons, *i.e.* `option1btn`, I want all the rows with the class `option1` to be shown, if I click `option2btn`, I want rows all with class `option2` to be shown, and so on.
More then one buttons can be selected to show more then one options.

Here is a code example:

```
<input id="option1btn" type="checkbox"> 
<input id="option2btn" type="checkbox"> 
<input id="option3btn" type="checkbox"> 
<input id="option4btn" type="checkbox">

<table id="optionTable">
    <tr class="option1">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option1">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option2 option4">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option1 option4">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option4">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option1 option3 option4">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option4">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I currently use css to add different background color to odd/even rows. Would like that to work so that it applies the colors on the rows currently shown so I won't have two rows with the same color.

Comment: The question is tagged jQuery.. Perhaps show us your jQuery code?

Comment: Well. I don't have one. Perhaps it is wrong of me to have others write the whole thing for me but right now I don't know where to start. Have looked around but haven't found something that works the way I want it, with multiple rows with same class. Looking at jQuery now to understand it more but I haven't really worked with it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't know where to start, I'll explain bit by bit.
You want to implement a *table filter*. Functional requirements are:

- When a checkbox is checked, the corresponding rows should be visible.
- When a checkbox is unchecked, the corresponding rows should be hidden, *only if no other checked checkbox corresponds to those rows*.

If it weren't for the part in italics, you could just `show` and `hide`. When a checkbox is unchecked you have to check first which other option classes the row has, and, using a [flag variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402125/what-is-a-flag-variable) (`hide` in the example below), decide whether it should be toggled.
For ease of use, map the `<input type="checkbox">` value attribute to the classname of the rows each should toggle:

```
<input id="option1btn" type="checkbox" value="option1">
<input id="option2btn" type="checkbox" value="option2"> 
<input id="option3btn" type="checkbox" value="option3"> 
<input id="option4btn" type="checkbox" value="option4">
```

And here's the code. Not sure how familiar you are with JS/jQuery but this is required knowledge to understand the answer (don't worry, these are 2minute reads): [jQuery and 'this'](https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified), [jQuery Attribute 'starts with' selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), [jQuery variable naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign), [JS Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
var $options = $('[id^="option"]');
$options.on('change', function() {
  var $elementsToToggle = $('.' + this.value); // e.g. '.option3'
  if (this.checked) {
    // showing is simple
    $elementsToToggle.show();
  } else {
    // hiding must be done on a per-row basis
    $elementsToToggle.each(function() {
      var hide = true,
          elementToToggle = this;
      // check whether other checked filters should keep the row visible
      $options.each(function() {
        var checkbox = this,
            optionClass = checkbox.value,
            optionIsChecked = checkbox.checked;
        if (elementToToggle.classList.contains(optionClass) && optionIsChecked)
          hide = false;
      });

      if (hide === true)
        $(elementToToggle).hide();
    });
  }
});
```

#### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ckdc53wv/5/)

*(note: for easily checking correctness I replaced the row text with the option classes)*

Comment: This demo seems to work as I want it. Will try to decipher the code to get it to work with what I have.

Comment: @MAlgol Could you then [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Jquery check this out

HTML

```
<input id="option1btn" type="checkbox"> 
<input id="option2btn" type="checkbox"> 
<input id="option3btn" type="checkbox"> 
<input id="option4btn" type="checkbox">

<table id="optionTable">
    <tr class="option1">
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option1">
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option2 option4">
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option1 option4">
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option4">
        <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option1 option3 option4">
        <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="option4">
        <td>g</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.option1,.option2,.option3,.option4 {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Jquery

```
$("#option1btn").on('click',function() {
console.log("asas");
    $('.option1').toggleClass('show');
})
$("#option2btn").on('click',function() {
    $('.option2').toggleClass('show');
})
$("#option3btn").on('click',function() {
    $('.option3').toggleClass('show');
})
$("#option4btn").on('click',function() {
    $('.option4').toggleClass('show');
})
```

Working JS fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ckdc53wv/

Comment: Unfortunately this also hides previously checked options

Comment: So can you please bit more clear i can give you the exact code what you are looking for

Comment: I notice a strange effect with this. When I have more columns in the table all the rows end up in the first one.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      var checkCounter = {};
      var regExp = /^(option[0-9])btn$/;

      $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(e) {

        var matches = regExp.exec($(this).attr("id"));
        var checkbox = this;
        var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");

        $('#optionTable tr').each(function() {

          var rowIndex = $(this).index();
          var row = this;

          if (isNaN(checkCounter[rowIndex])) { checkCounter[rowIndex] = 0; }

          if ($(row).hasClass(matches[1])) {

            if (isChecked) {
              checkCounter[rowIndex] += 1;
              $(row).hide();
            } else {
              checkCounter[rowIndex] -= 1;
              if(checkCounter[rowIndex] == 0) {
                $(row).show();
              }
            }
          }
        });
      });
  </script>
```