# Deleting childNodes from parentNode

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

1 - I am adding Div container using JS but once their Counter crosses '5' i want to delete these Div containers **ONE BY ONE** from [0] index.

2 - Here below is what i have done so far.in which i am even getting the childNodes's Number but i am not able to delete these nodes..

```js
var counter = 0;

function add_div() {
  var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main-div");

  var divi = document.createElement("DIV");
  divi.setAttribute("ID", "div_id");
  divi.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  divi.style.height = "50px";
  divi.style.width = "50px";
  divi.style.margin = "20px";
  mainDiv.appendChild(divi);
  document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  counter += 1;
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter;

  //read nodes
  var ch = document.getElementById("main-div").childElementCount;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "number of childNodes: " + ch;

  //counter check
  if (counter > 5) {
    mainDiv.removeChild(mainDiv.childNodes[0]);
    // mainDiv.parentNode.removeChild(mainDiv);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add_div()">ADD DIV</button>
<div id="count"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="main-div"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: It's deleting the DIVs like you want, what's the problem?

Comment: When you delete the DIV, you never decrement `counter`. Also, you display `number of childnodes` before you delete the DIV, so the count includes the deleted DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first decremented your counter to update for both negative and positive values. I then set a [flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402125/what-is-a-flag-variable) to detect if your code was decrementing or not. When counter reached 5, decrement is set to `true`, where when counter is moving towards 5, decrement is set to `false`.

Then your div's were added to an array, where we use a [`for loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) to traverse through the array, removing a div one by one, until we reach 0, where decrement is set back to false;

```js
var counter = 0;

 let decrement = false;
function add_div() {
  if(!decrement){
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main-div");

  var divi = document.createElement("DIV");
  divi.setAttribute("ID", "div_id");
  divi.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  divi.style.height = "50px";
  divi.style.width = "50px";
  divi.style.margin = "20px";
  mainDiv.appendChild(divi);
  document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  counter ++;
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter;


 
  }
  
  //counter check
  if (counter > 5) {
    decrement = true;
  }
  if(counter <= 0){
      decrement = false;
    }
  if(decrement){
    counter--; //decrement counter
    let holder = [];                                     //place div ID's in array
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter; //update counter
    let div = document.querySelector('#div_id');           //grab div
    holder.push(div);                                        //push to array
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     holder[i].parentNode.removeChild(holder[i]) //removes child
    }
   
  }
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add_div()">ADD DIV</button>
<div id="count"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="main-div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! i didn't thought about adding flag :)

Comment: No problem (: Glad to help