# Querying the status of a bit flag?

Tags: c++

I am trying to parse some files that have a bitwise flag column. There are 11 bits in this flag and I need to find out, for each row in the files, what is the value of the 5th bit (1-based).

Comment: You need to provide more information.  How are the bits encoded into this file?  Is it ASCII hex?  Raw binary?

Comment: ASCII. The bits are encoded as a number (e.g., the first 3 rows have: 0, 4 and 16).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check my byte flag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127027/how-to-check-my-byte-flag)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (flags & 0x10) ....
```

how did I know that mask (0x10)

here are 8 bits

```
0b00000000
```

here is the fifth one starting from one (from the right)

```
  87654321        
0b00010000
```

and in hex that is

```
0x10
```

Comment: How do you calculate that the 5th flag is 0x10?

Comment: Because the bits are powers of two: 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80.  Just a fundamental property of the binary number system, each bit is twice the value of the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

May be overkill for small number of flags, but I find easier to manipulate bits using `std::bitset`.

First, "construct" a bitset of 11 bits from the `flags`.

```
std::bitset< 11 > flags_bitset( flags );
```

Then, "test" the fifth bit

```
if( flags_bitset.test( 4 ) {  // 4, because indexing is 0 based.
    /* something */
}
```

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/test/

For doing by hand, try

```
const uint32_t mask = 1U << 4;  // '1' in fifth bit and rest '0' 
if( flag & mask ) { .. }
```